# Configure Nginx for aws s3 static and media files

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3

I am using aws s3 for static and media files for my django app. Gunicorn and Nginx are being used for application and proxy server.

Nginx setup:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sitename.com;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/SiteNameDjango/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

Since I am using aws s3 for my static and media files, how should I configure Nginx for my static location? Or there's no need to configure for the static and media files?

If it helps, here is the Django project settings for aws s3:

```
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'myproject.custom_storages.StaticStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'myproject.custom_storages.MediaStorage'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "django-bucket"
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + ".s3.amazonaws.com"
STATIC_URL = "https://" + AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + ".s3.amazonaws.com/"
MEDIA_URL = STATIC_URL + "media/"
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + "admin/"
```

Eg url:

```
https://django-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/media/user_image/1497598249_49.jpeg
```

Answer (score 7):

In case of S3, nginx is not responsible for serving static and media files and you no need to configure anything.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using app server to serve the static files,then you need to configure nginx the way mattia has mentioned.

However you don't really need the same if you are using s3 path. Based on your configuration when your run collectstatic it should automatically sync your files on s3.

In you views you use the s3 , to have performance boost you can put your s3 behind Cloudfront and server content from there.

Comment: YES. USE CLOUDFRONT! Not just s3, otherwise it will be very slow.

Answer (score -2):

In Nginx try with:

```
location /static {
       alias /path/to/your/static;
    }
```

In Djando settings.py use:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/path/to/your/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

After this you need to collect statics in the folder, run the following command:

```
python manange.py collectstatic
```

Django will save all static files in the path specified, now Nginx will load the static files without the URL